# Using ColorBox onComplete in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, colorbox

I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but I've written little jQuery code and can't figure it out.  I'm using the ColorBox plugin for my WordPress website and would like to run some code after an image is displayed.  I've added the following code to my header.php file, but the alert is never called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.screenshot-image a').colorbox({
        onComplete:function(){
            alert('test');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Next time you should check your javascript console for errors.  You can't put a semicolon after an object value like that and you've included an extra ')'.  Try the following:

```
jQuery('.screenshot-image a').colorbox({
    onComplete:function(){
        alert('test');
    }
});
```

Also, be sure to wait until the DOM has loaded before doing any of this.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that, I'm still getting the hang of firebug debugging.  After fixing the code I found another "colorbox is not a function" bug which I think was the root cause of the problem.  It turns out the plugin only adds jquery.colorbox-min.js and jquery-colorbox-wrapper-min.js in the page header.  So I added jquery.colorbox.js to my header.php file and things started working as expected.  The callbacks on the example page of your website helped me track it down.

Answer (score 1):

you can try `promise()` and `done()` methods

```
$('.screenshot-image a').colorbox().promise().done(function(){
   alert('test')
})
```